# Strange result for decision-tree-classifier. Why?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm still in touch with DT-Classification and try to understand how the Mathematica algorithms works and what tree is generated (related: [click](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/204003/properties-of-a-decision-tree-generated-by-a-classifier)). I just tested the well-known "playing tennis" (sometimes "playing golf") example. The data is as follows:

```
 data = {{"outlook", "temperature", "humidity", "wind", 
    "play"}, {"sunny", "hot", "high", "weak", "no"}, {"sunny", "hot", 
    "high", "strong", "no"}, {"overcast", "hot", "high", "weak", 
    "yes"}, {"rainy", "mild", "high", "weak", "yes"}, {"rainy", 
    "cold", "normal", "weak", "yes"}, {"rainy", "cold", "normal", 
    "strong", "no"}, {"overcast", "cold", "normal", "strong", 
    "yes"}, {"sunny", "mild", "high", "weak", "no"}, {"sunny", "cold",
     "normal", "weak", "yes"}, {"rainy", "mild", "normal", "weak", 
    "yes"}, {"sunny", "mild", "normal", "strong", "yes"}, {"overcast",
     "mild", "high", "strong", "yes"}, {"overcast", "hot", "normal", 
    "weak", "yes"}, {"rainy", "mild", "high", "strong", "no"}};
```

the input for classification:

```
input = Rest @ Thread[data[[All, ;; 4]] -> data[[All, 5]]]
```

The attribute space we have:

```
allAttributes = Union /@ Table[data[[All, i]], {i, 1, 4}]
```

and all possible inputs (not only the given 14 ones):

```
allTuples = Tuples[allAttributes];
```

with an `Automatic` classification we get:

```
   cfAutomatic = Classify[input];
cfAutomatic /@ allTuples // Tally
```

(* {{"yes", 30}, {"no", 6}} *)

with a `DecisionTree` we get

```
    cfTree = Classify[input, Method -> "DecisionTree"];
cfTree /@ allTuples // Tally
```

(* {{"yes", 36}} *)

This is "interesting". The given example can be found very widespread in literature with appropriate DT calculated using, e.g. Gini-Index and ID3 or CART). This result is clearly not "correct" - or I made a stupid error. Can anyone give a hint what goes wrong or what I did wrong?